# How does reflection work on resource repositories

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resources

I want to understand how such a code works to retrieve the resource of the specified ThreadUI Culture?

```
var value = resourceAssembly
      .GetType("Namespace.FooBar")
      .GetProperty("Hello")
      .GetValue(null, null) as string;
```

If my ThreadUI Culture is english, I get the english value. If it is german, I get the german value.
Ok, fine. But how does it work inside?

Comment: The code snippet is very misleading, what you call "resourceAssembly" is almost definitely not an assembly that contains the resources.  Which are normally stored in satellite assemblies, containing no code.  Improve the snippet and show us how you got the "resourceAssembly" reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open up the generated C# file corresponding to that type, you'll see something like this:

```
internal static string Hello {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("Hello", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

Unless you *specific* `resourceCulture` (by setting the `Culture` property) it will still be `null`, so the above will be equivalent to:

```
return ResourceManager.GetString("Hello", null);
```

The `ResourceManager` property returns a `System.Resources.ResourceManager`, and if you look at the docs for [`ResourceManager.GetString(string, CultureInfo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsb0cfet(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see:

> In desktop apps, if *culture* is `null`, the `GetString(String, CultureInfo)` method uses the current UI culture obtained from the `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` property.

So that's all it is - just a call to a library method which uses the current UI culture by default.

Comment: Thank you @Jon, I was wrong, seeking the solution in the implementation of GetValue()